# Как удалить записи из таблицы MYSQL которые были созданы более 3 минут назад?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я не силен в работе с датами. В таблице есть поле с датой создания записи (mydate) в формате TIMESTAMP.

Надо удалить записи, которые были созданы более 3 минут (180 сек) назад?

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE NOW() - mydate > 180
```

Не работает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это должно решить проблему:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE  mydate < (NOW()  - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
```